# can't accss to eloquent relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

i'm having a real weird problem in accessing eloquent relation in laravel 7

i use the "has-one" eloquent relationship

when i dump the data it returns like this

[this shows the object with it's relations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IHj7.png)

when i try access the relations through $subject->description

it returns null like this

[returns null on accessing the relation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ICz9.png)

it's weird and first time it happens to me

Comment: provide your model and the schema for this table

Answer (score 0):

you can user foreach in blade example

```
@foreach($subject->description as $description)
{{ $description->id }}
{{ $description->subject_id }}
...

@endforeach
```

or in the controller

```
foreach($subject->description as $description){
    $description->id;
    $description->subject_id;
}
```

Comment: It's a has one not has many to make for each
And I can't access the relationship at all to even make that

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try if you use `"belongs to"` then you can access data without looping .